# Laravel 5 Multi-Tenancy App with separate databases - users have access to multiple installations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, multi-tenant

Over the past couple of years I have developed a very customised PHP/MySQL application that is used for a number of clients. I have been creating a new database and new installation for each client up to this point.

The first obvious problem here is keeping multiple installations up to date with any code changes; a second problem is that each installation has a large amount of users; and for most clients; some of these users are the same - and they have to have a number of seperate user accounts and urls to remember.

I am moving the application over to Laravel 5 at the moment and looking into the best implementation for multi-tenancy; so looking for a little advice on the best implementation. I've used Laravel before but am by no means an expert.

This is what I am thinking as far as setup.

**1 Master Database that holds tables for:**

1. All User account information
2. Access Control Table - which installations the users can access; what their user level on that installation is.
3. Configuration table for each installation - database connection info, basic configuration etc.

**Then a seperate database for each installation that contains all the information that is needed for, and submitted to, that installation.**

The ideal setup is that a user can go to a subdomain i.e installationname.appname.com; sign in with their master login details and automatically go to the required installation; OR go to appname.com, sign in and then select which installation to connect to.

**My questions are:**

1. Is this the best arrangement to achieve what I am looking for.
2. What's the best method for storing which installation the user is looking at (session variable)
3. Can I define a model between 2 databases - perhaps define one connection as master connection, then dynamically define another connection using the database connection information in the master database to connect to the correct installation. - the system will often need to check the user info for access level etc.

I'm sure there's a lot of issues that I have not thought of; but if anyone has any links or guidance that may help that would be great. First time asking a question on SO but have found a huge amount of research help here in the past so thanks to the community!

---

UPDATE - So I think I have a way to make this work now; using seperate databases as above; set

```
protected $connection = 'tenant_connection'
```

in the models relating to tenant-specific database content.

Then somewhere in a header file set the tenant_connection that is wanted based on a session variable which has been set on login/by subdomain.

```
$tenant = Installation::where('installation', '=', $session['installation'])->first();
Config::set('database.connections.tenant_connection', array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => $tenant->db_hostname, 'username' => $tenant->db_username)... etc.
```

Assuming relationships will work across connections; I don't see why this would not work; just need to work out best place to set the tenant connection.

Comment: Just curious, were you able to get this fully functional? If so, could you post your solution as an answer? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: I would love the same...I am looking exactly what you did for you...

Comment: I'll try and post what I did now as an answer though it may make little sense!

Answer (score 4):

Ok so what I ended up doing was having all user info, names of installations and mappings of what users can access what installations in one database, and all tenant info in seperate databases.

I then had two connections, mysql and mysql_tenant; where mysql_tenant database is not pre-set but dynamic.

The User, Installations and mappings model use the mysql connection, all others use mysql_tenant

Created a code for each installation, and used this as the name of the tenant database; storing this code in the session.

Used a middleware MultiTenant, to control the switching between installations using these key lines:

```
$tenant_id = session()->get('tenant');

\Config::set('database.connections.mysql_tenant.database', $dbname);
\DB::setDefaultConnection('mysql_tenant');
```

There's a lot more to it for building the method to switch etc, but this is the gist.

Comment: can you post an in depth answer as I have the same situation of multiple entries in relation to geographical data!

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to answer most of your question - as it is specific to your application and opinion based.

But the one bit I can answer is different models can have different database connections. So your `user` model uses the normal default connection - but your other models can use another connection:

```
class Example extends Model {

    protected $connection= 'second_db_connection';

}
```

Then in your DB connection file - you would have something like this:

```
return array(
    'connections' => array(
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'database1',
            'username'  => 'user1',
            'password'  => 'pass1'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        'second_db_connection' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'database2',
            'username'  => 'user2',
            'password'  => 'pass2'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks - I think the question here is that either the second database connection name would need to be defined dynamically in the model; with all possible connections listed in the DB connection file; or the details of the second database connection would need to be dynamically defined from the master database - so not sure which of these would work best/be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5 is advanced enough that you should be able to have simply one installation along with a strategic database, with well defined relations and keys. There is rarely ever a need for multiple databases.

If you can be more specific about your requirements I can provide a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; the reason for multiple databases is twofold, firstly for speed of searches - there will be up to 6,000 entries per table in some installations. Secondly, the application is for use in registering personnel for event work; then checking them in on site - sometimes there is no internet connection on site so I need to use a local server setup, in this instance I would just want to take the specific database I need offline and import onto the local server; then re-upload online afterwards. Having one database would cause issues here.

Comment: In my case customers require their data to be inside their own country, and completely separate from other customers. This is due to legal requirements. So there is definitely a use case for separating databases.