# Laravel 5 Multi-Tenancy with separate databases - apply tenant connection to all DB queries

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I wanted my Laravel web app to be multi-tenant with one common database for authentification and specific databases for my clients.

Thanks to some [good readings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942145/laravel-5-multi-tenancy-app-with-separate-databases-users-have-access-to-multi), I figured out how to do so with an appropriate middleware.

Under `config\database` I added my tenant connection :

```
'tenant_mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => '',
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        ...]
```

And then made a dedicated `MultiTenant` middleware:

```
...

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $tenant_db = Auth::user()->tenant_db;
        Config::set('database.connections.tenant_mysql.database', $tenant_db);

        return $next($request);
    }
```

To finish I applied the `tenant_mysql` connection to the wanted `Model` by adding :

```
protected $connection = 'tenant_mysql';
```

And it works great!

My issue starts with correctly configuring my `DB::raw`, `DB::table` , ... `queries` which I have in my app.

I thought the above created would be a good place to set up the connection so I updated it :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $tenant_db = Auth::user()->tenant_db;

    DB::purge('tenant_mysql');                       //line added
    Config::set('database.connections.tenant_mysql.database', $tenant_db);

    DB::reconnect('tenant_mysql');                   //line added

    return $next($request);
}
```

but with no effect on the queries.

Hopefully someone can shed some light..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection is already setup, you just have to use `DB::connection('tenant_mysql')->select(...);` or if you want to set it globally you can change your `environment (.env)` file and change variable called `DB_CONNECTION` to `tenant_mysql` like: `DB_CONNECTION=tenant_mysql`

Comment: This is a solution but I hopped to set it up globally

Comment: Then you can set inside of your `.env` file this line: `DB_CONNECTION=tenant_mysql`

Comment: This has a little downside, it would affect the connection used for the Authentification

Comment: Well how are you supposed to set it globally then? Best approach would be to use `DB::connection` in the case where your `Authentication` is working on another `db`

Comment: I finally ended up by using `DB::connection('tenant_mysql')->...` on my queries